# Javascript Testing with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, continuous-integration

I'd like to know:

How do you test your javascript in your Rails App?

I used to do Integration Tests with `capybara`, but now that I'm working on a map-based solution with rails, that has a far more complex javascript part than the rails part, capybara feels really kludgy.

Also, I'd like to execute javascript tests that not only test the interface, but also particular javascript functions.

I heard about `mocha`, but I don't really know if its possible to integrate it so that my test are executed on my CI Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you exactly want to test but i love Jasmine :)

Here is also a cool [RailsCast to JavaScript Testing with Jasmine](http://railscasts.com/episodes/261-testing-javascript-with-jasmine?view=asciicast)

Also cool is for Rails Testing (javascript):
[TeaSpoon](https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon) and [Karma](http://danott.co/posts/rails-javascript-testing-using-karma.html)

A good look at first is always: [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/javascript_testing)

Comment: Thanks mate, `teaspoon` does exactly what I wanted and integrates seamlessly with CircleCI.
I encourage everyone to check it out!